# Как сбросить форму к начальному состоянию? Как скопировать начальное состояние формы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Нужно при клике на кнопку "Сбросить" откатить форму к её начальному состоянию. `reset` - работает, за одним нюансом - селекты не сбрасываются.
Пример селекта:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="id_big-experience_total" name="big-experience_total" title="общий стаж" tabindex="-98">
      <option class="bs-title-option" value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="id_big-experience_total" title="общий стаж">
      <div class="filter-option">
        <div class="filter-option-inner">
          <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">общий стаж</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu " role="combobox">
      <div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть при сбрасывании на селекте должен писаться `title`.
Поэтому либо нужно как-то допиливать, либо же есть второй вариант. Скопировать начальное состояние формы при загрузке странице и при нажатии на "Сбросить" вместо заполненной формы подставлять изначально скопированный элемент. Пробовал так сделать: копирую изначальную форму (`var form = $('form')`), но когда подставляю её - в ней всё-равно есть ранее введённые данные.

Какие есть варианты решения?

*Начальное состояние*

[image: Начальное состояние]

*Заполнил*

[image: Заполнил]

*Сбросил*

[image: Сбросил]

Comment: Как вы очищаете её? Код киньте... Можно вручную это делать.. Аля `$('form').find('select').val($('form').find('select').attr('title'));` а вообще лучше использовать `defaultSelected`

Comment: через `$('form').reset()` пробовал - очищается всё, кроме селектов.

Comment: Я так понимаю, чтобы Ваш вариант работал для всех селектов, нужно `this` применить?

Comment: `reset()` предпочтительней моего варт-ра будет.. а так-то он должен и для вашего select работать - [тык](https://jsfiddle.net/90osy6n4/) выложите полностью свой не рабочий код...

Comment: Вот - https://jsfiddle.net/zyvLu4x2/

Comment: Я так понимаю, это связано с тем, что title с button'a берётся...

Comment: А можно ещё скрин увидеть что именно не сбрасывается? У меня всё норм там где вы кинули

Comment: В описание добавил скрины

Comment: Как-то так очищает? `$('#id_big-experience_total').val('');` после строки с reset() если добавить..

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не очищает. Смотрите. Там есть под селектами блок - button. Название в селект прилетает с него... Когда я выбираю какое-то значение, это значение заносится в `<div class="filter-option-inner-inner">`. Так что нужно откатывать к начальному значению именно этот элемент, я так понимаю. И как я понимаю, его можно брать из `<select title >` (так как там это значение не меняется).

Comment: Вот как оно работает. - `$('button[data-id="id_big-experience_total"] > div > div > .filter-option-inner-inner').text($('#id_big-experience_total').attr('title'));` Осталось только оптимизировать под n-ое количество селектов.

Comment: Добавил решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.exteneded_form_reset').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("big_form").reset();
    $.each($('div.form-control'), function() {
        $(this).find('.filter-option-inner-inner').text($(this).find('select.form-control').attr('title'));
    })
})
```

Comment: А `text()` не заменяет содержимое селектов?

Comment: нет, не заменяет